# Android Studio [] brackets

Tags: android-studio

I can't write "[" or "]" in Android Studio, because there's some shortcut making refactoring code. I would like to delete this shortcut, but I can't find it in Keymap. So for me only way how to write [] is copy it from other text editor, which isn't best you know.

Any idea where exactly can be this shortcut deleted?

Comment: tip: instead of copying it from another texteditor, type ][ and the swap position?

Comment: I can't write ] or [  neither. [ does some refactoring, ] nothing.

Comment: Oh, I see, I thought it was the combination of both that brought up the refactoring. Have you any addon installed? If its common in android(I don't know) to type [] then it might be a problem from any addon you might have, that's all I got. good luck with it tho ;)

Comment: I use just pure AS without any addons, so really dunno what's going on here. Thanks for idea anyway.
btw: question edited to "or" instead of "and" now.